# Where can I get informations about smartphones battery datasheet?

Tags: battery-operated

I'm hardly trying to find the datasheets and I still got nothing :(, what I was try to find is like Asus battery for Zenfone 4 Model: C11P1404 datasheet. Please for your kindness tell me where can I find that one :)

Comment: It's very likely a custom design for the phone maker, and the specs are proprietary.

Comment: Even if it weren't a custom battery for the phone maker (which it almost certainly is), it's very unlikely that the battery manufacturer would provide information on it.